# Word Press PHP ACF Snippets in JS functions

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently adding in Advanced Custom Fields for my site but when I try and add an ACF snippet to any of the functions the content doesn't show in the browser and all my js code in the script tags stop working and displaying in the browser. what am I doing wrong?

the js code is in script tags in the front-page.php file

```
    function changeTestimonial1(){
    document.getElementById("client-name").innerHTML ="<?php the_field('client_name1'); ?>";
}
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] - “doesn’t work” does not work for us, as a problem description.

Comment: What does the generated HTML code look like? Where are you calling the function? Does the browser console have anything to say?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest constructing your html/php/javascript as such:

```
<?php
    $somevar = 1234;
?>
<HTML>
    <script language="JavaScript">  
        // JS will contain value of php variable $somevar, but make sure you escape the value.
        var some_js_var = <?php echo $somevar; ?>
    </script>
</HTML>
```